# How to know where's the first function argument?

Tags: function, assembly, x86, arguments, cpu-registers

I was just wondering, If I have this ASM function:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
SUB ESP, 8
LEAVE
RETN 8
```

That does nothing and takes two 4-bytes arguments. It seems that the first argument is at `EBP+8` and the second at `EBP+12`. But, how to know that? Because if the function takes three 4-bytes parameters, then the third will be at `EBP+16`. Will the first argument be always at `EBP+8` and then I just have to add the argument size to get the next one? If yes, why 8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first **stack** argument will always be at `[EBP+8]` when using a stack frame, but calling conventions can pass arguments in both registers (general purpose and SIMD) and on the stack.

This your example assume you use a standardized convention such as `__stdcall`, `__cdecl` but arguments in `__fastcall` and VC++13's new `__vectorcall` will be in general purpose and SIMD registers respectively (and the registers themselves differ based on ABI Sys-V vs MS).

Comment: Ok, that's enough for me! I'm using the `__stdcall` convention. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's at 8 because, generally, EBP+0 = caller's saved EBP, EBP+4 = return address, EBP+8 = first stack based argument.

Also, offsets like this are normally expressed in hexadecimal values so the 2nd stack based argument will be at EBP+C and the third will be at EBP+10.

A good way (not 100% though) to deduce the calling convention of the function is to see how callers of the function prepare registers and/or the stack just prior to calling the function (and also just after the function returns).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll mark Necrolis' answers because he answered first, but both help me! +1. Also, I'm executing that ASM code using the `__asm` statement from the VC++ compiler, and it automatically converts all numeric values into hexadecimal values, that's why I'm using 8, 12, 16. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Layout of function arguments depends on calling convention being used for this function. And the calling convention can be anything that the function creator was potent to imagine.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help me very much.

Comment: You should be more specific about what you want to know to get better answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I'm specific. How I know where's the first argument of the function?

Comment: In retrospection I would say you could specify the question was about `__stdcall`.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thanks for your answer too.